# Converting Legacy SQL Query to Standard SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, legacy-sql

I am looking to convert the below Legacy SQL Query to Standard SQL. The issue I am having is that I need to unnest two tables (labels and credits). How can I convert this query? Thanks!

I run into a "Scalar subquery produced more than one element" whenever I try to rewrite this query (see below).

**Legacy SQL Query I am trying to rewrite:**

```
SELECT
  service.description,
  sku.description,
  usage_start_time,
  usage_end_time,
  labels.key,
  labels.value,
  cost,
  usage.amount,
  project.name,
  credits.name,
  credits.amount
FROM
  flatten([gcp_billing_data.gcp_billing_export],
    credits)
```

**What I have tried so far in Standard SQL:**

```
SELECT
  service.description AS service,
  sku.description AS sku,
  usage_start_time,
  usage_end_time,
  l.key,
  l.value,
  cost,
  usage.amount AS usage,
  project.name AS project,
  c.name AS credit,
  c.amount
FROM
  `gcp_billing_data.gcp_billing_export`,
  UNNEST(labels) AS l,
  UNNEST(credits) AS c
Group by 1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9,10,11
```

This query runs, but the number of rows is significantly less than I would expect.

Comment: To me personally - the original query you are using  - looks not kosher at all - as it duplicates multiple times cost and credits across the labels - so total results will end up in x times larger than in real. So, if you can provide simplified example of input data and expected output - and explain what exactly you want to get - this will expedite the answer :o)

Comment: ... while quick and formal fix is something like to replace `(select l.value from unnest(labels) as l)` with `(select string_agg(l.value) from unnest(labels) as l)`

Comment: and what about credits?? should it be cross join with labels?

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant I am not quite sure. You can see in the legacy SQL all I need to do is select the labels. So I am not sure the nature of the join via flatten and ",". I assume that is a cross join? Thanks for your help in your previous comment. That query now runs.

Comment: ok. so, btw, that is why I asked you to post simplified example of input and output so we can help you to understand what/how it should work. meantime - if it works  for you - I will post it as an answer :o)

Comment: I am aware. As I stated, this answer does not address my original questions, which is converting the top legacy SQL query to Standard.

Comment: got it. this was not clear before! even though i am still not clear on ti  - but you own your post so up to you :o)

Answer (score 1):

quick and formal fix for your query in Standard SQL is something like to replace below

```
(select l.value from unnest(labels) as l)
```

with

```
(select string_agg(l.value) from unnest(labels) as l)
```

But it is still not exactly the same as what initial version of your Legacy SQL version of query is doing

Comment: Thank you for posting this, although this solves the error I was seeing in my attempted solution, I agree with your previous comment that this does not mirror the original query.

Comment: I have updated the query in my original question based on your comments, but am seeing significantly fewer rows in the result than I would expect. Your thoughts would be greatly appreciated.